# Radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{\cosh(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I know (wrongly I found out!) that $\frac{1}{\cosh(z)}=1+\frac{2}{z^2}+\frac{24}{z^4}+...$ centered at the origin.

Does this mean that the radius of convergence is 0 since the only singularity is at the origin as well? So the distance from the origin to a singularity is 0?

I am confused about this. 
Thanks.

Comment: You have in effect assumed $\frac1{a+b+c+\cdots}=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\cdots\,$.

Comment: An expansion in negative powers converges at $\infty$ and possibly a neighborhood of it.

Comment: @David Oh oops. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence is the distance in the complex plane to the nearest singularity. Now $\cosh (z) = 0$ when $z= \pm \pi \mathrm{i}/2$, so the radius of convergence is $\pi/2$.

Comment: Oh thank you. So I don't want to use the taylor series then to determine it?

Comment: Well I believe your series is incorrect, but essentially yes, it would be difficult to compute this using a series.

Comment: I see that it is. Oops! thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you perform the expansion around $z=0$, you effectively have
$$\cosh(z)=1+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}+\frac{z^6}{720}+\frac{z^8}{40320}+O\left(z^{10}\right)$$ making
$$\frac 1 {\cosh(z)}=\frac 1{1+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}+\frac{z^6}{720}+\frac{z^8}{40320}+O\left(z^{10}\right) }$$ Using long division
$$\frac 1 {\cosh(z)}=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{5 z^4}{24}-\frac{61 z^6}{720}+\frac{277
   z^8}{8064}+O\left(z^{10}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve this equation in the complex numbers:

$$\cosh(z) = 0.$$

You will now know the radius of convergence of the Taylor expansion.