# Maclaurin series of $\frac{2}{1+ \cosh(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series of $f(z)= \frac{2}{1+ cosh(z)} $.

I've tried substituting for z in the known series $ \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{z^n}$ with known radius of convergence $|z| < 1$, and get the  following:

$$ \frac{2}{1+\cosh (z)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n (e^z + e^{-z})^n}$$

$$|\cosh{z}| < 1 \Rightarrow  |\frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{2}|<1 \Rightarrow |z| < \pi i$$

The radius of convergence is therefore $\pi$.

1. Does this reasoning make sense?
2. I'm unable to get any further with the series above. How can I convert it into a power series?
3. The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636445/radius-of-convergence-of-frac1-coshz) states that the radius of convergence is the distance in the complex plane to the nearest singularity, which makes the problem much easier - one can just set the denominator equal to 0 and solve for $z$, which gives the same answer. However, this seems to assume that every function is analytic everywhere except at singularities, an assumption I have trouble justifying.

Comment: The problem is not all expansions have nice derivatives. Try expanding $( \sech ( \frac{z}{2} ))^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes little sense since:
$$\cosh z\ge 1$$
along the real axis so that you cannot apply the formula for geometric series which is valid only for $|z|<1$.

The reasoning (3.) is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How does one get around (or prove) the assumption that the function is analytic everywhere except at singularities?

Comment: If a function $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere and has only isolated zeros  its reciprocal $1/f(z)$ is analytic everywhere except for zeros of $f(z)$.